# Making a ComboBox appear when a check box is filled in

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, combobox

I looked around and I saw some things related to java, but nothing for C#/WPF. What I'm trying to do is just what the questions says. For example if "Microsoft" is checked I want a Combobox to appear in the second panel, so that they can select "Windows", "Xbox" or what have you. Hope the question makes sense. I did some googling but I'm still really new at programming so I'm probably just missing something basic. I tried this

```
private void Microsoft_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox_Copy.isEnabled = (Microsoft.CheckState == 
  CheckState.Checked);
    }
```

But it says CheckState does not exist in the current context, as well as "combobox does not have a definition for enabled"

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  Please refer to the code below which I believe would be closer to your method and should fix your problems..  Your problem I believe lies in the two different parts.  You are trying to use the isEnabled variable in the place of the visability variable which I believe is better suited for the task.  Also you have tried to use an equivilence operator (Equals) between two different variable types, as the output from a ticked or unticked box is not a Boolean output, at least not from what I've seen of WPF.

```
private void Microsoft_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var resultFromCheckBox = sender as CheckBox; // This line acts as a link between the check box (i.e. Microsoft) and this function so you can use resultFromCheckBox instead of Microsoft.      

  if (resultFromCheckBox.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
  {
      comboBox_Copy.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; // Sets box to visible if checkbox is selected
  }
  else
  {
      comboBox_Copy.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden; // Sets to hidden in all other cases i.e. when it is not selected.
  }
}
```

Previous answer:

The code you have shown at least in Windows Forms, I'm fairly sure it is similar in WPF, would allow the control to become active (it can be interacted with).  The visability variable might be of more use.

I believe the code you are looking for is something along the lines of the following:

```
private void Microsoft_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (comboBox_Copy.Visibility != System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
  {
      comboBox_Copy.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
  }
  else
  {
      comboBox_Copy.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
  }
}
```

The visability property shows or hides the box in question.  I just made it alternate depending on if the box was visible or not in the first place.  You could alternately use the event arguments to check if the tickbox is checked and respond that way.

Hope it helps.